# What's the difference between register_chrdev() and register_chrdev_region()?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I'm currently studying Linux device drivers and am confused between two similar static device registration functions:

1. `register_chrdev()`
2. `register_chrdev_region()`

These functions both statically register device drivers. The first function registers a single device driver while the latter registers a range of device drivers.

What confuses me is that a single device driver can handle access to many instances of the same device. Thus for a given device type, only a single device driver should ever be registered. Multiple devices can then reference this driver by multiple `mknod` calls.

So my question, what is the difference between these two functions in how they should be used?

Answer (score 4):

The `struct file_operations *fops` is assigned to a `struct cdev` which is part of the mechanism for accessing character devices in modern Linux kernels (actually since kernel version 2.5.70). `register_chrdev()` predates the introduction of `struct cdev` and allocates a `struct cdev` internally on behalf of the caller. This `struct cdev` will be deallocated by a call to the matching deregistration function `unregister_chrdev()`.  `__register_chrdev()` is similar to `register_chrdev()` but allows the base minor number and count of minor devices to be specified (`register_chrdev(major, name, fops)` is equivalent to `__register_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name, fops)`). The matching deregistration function is `__unregister_chrdev()`.

`register_chrdev_region()` is more recent and expects the caller to manage the `struct cdev` objects by itself. There are two common patterns: either a single `struct cdev` is used for the whole range of `dev_t` values registered by `register_chrdev_region()`, or a `struct cdev` is created dynamically for a single `dev_t` value on demand when the driver's `probe` function sets up a device. (A `dev_t` value is a combination of major and minor device number.)

`alloc_chrdev_region()` is similar to `register_chrdev_region()` but always chooses the major device number dynamically.

The matching deregistration function for `register_chrdev_region()` and `alloc_chrdev_region()` is `unregister_chrdev_region()`.

Internally, the above `alloc_`, `register_` and `__register_` functions call `__register_chrdev_region()` to reserve the range of `dev_t` values, and the above `unregister_` and `__unregister` functions call `__unregister_chrdev_region()` to release the reserved `dev_t` values. (`__register_chrdev_region()` and `__unregister_chrdev_region()` are internal functions with no external linkage outside of "fs/char_dev.c".)

Code that uses the newer interface needs `cdev_alloc()` to allocate a `struct cdev` or `cdev_init()` to initialize an existing, not yet initialized `struct cdev`. (`cdev_init()` also sets the `ops` member of the `struct cdev` to the supplied file operations pointer. Callers of `cdev_alloc()` need to assign the file operations pointer to the `ops` member themselves.) The function `cdev_add()` binds the `struct cdev` to a range of one or more `dev_t` values that has been previously registered by `register_chrdev_region()` or `alloc_chrdev_region()`. `cdev_del()` undoes the effect of `cdev_add()` and/or frees a `struct cdev` that was allocated by `cdev_alloc()`.